# Why is the square of the magnitude of a spherical harmonic function related to the zenith angle $θ$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, spherical-harmonics

My intuition tells me that the wave function corresponding to a spherically symmetric potential should only depend on r (of course, intuition can be misleading), otherwise changing the orientation of the coordinate axis would alter the probability density of the wave function.
The integration of PDF:

[image: Introduction to Quantum Mechanics,David J. Griffiths, page 136]

The spherical harmonies:

[image: page 137]

The wave functions:

[image: page 141]

Assuming that the square of the magnitude of a spherical harmonic function is related to the zenith angle θ, then under normal circumstances, the wave function, multiplied by θ, would also be dependent on θ. Does this imply that changing the coordinate system would lead to a variation in the probability density function (I mean the entire function graph rotates along with the coordinate axes as we change them. But that's impossible in my view, because the PDF should be independent with the choice of the axes), and suggest that the probability density function is not spherically symmetric (related to θ)?

If you could help me clear up my confusion, I would be immensely grateful!

Comment: Are you asking for the reason of the $\sin\theta$ term in the integral? This comes from the Jacobian of the conversion from Cartiesian to spherical coordinates, and reflects the fact that the poles are points on the actual surface but are stretched to lines in $\theta,\phi$ coordinates.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is very misleading, as you appreciate it can be. You got the average right. Look at the angular pictures of the spherical harmonics, and possibly focus your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the $z$-axis is entirely arbitrary, so it seems strange that a spherically symmetric potential would have solutions that depend on polar angle.

$l=0$ is spherically symmetric, so that is trivial.

The next order, $l=1$, provides a simple example of how to resolve this conundrum. As you state in the question, the solutions look like one $\cos{\theta}$ and two $\sin{\theta}$ solutions. Note that $Y_1^0 \propto z$, while $Y_1^{\pm 1} \propto x \mp iy$, so you can take linear combinations (the real spherical harmonics) and get:

$$ x, y, z $$

If you apply an arbitrary rotation, you can make new linear combinations that look like:

$$ x', y', z'$$

so nothing has changed physically, it's just that the mathematical description has changed coordinates: and atoms (for example) don't know about you coordinate choices. (Note that eigenstates' energy won't depend on $m$, so you really can mix them at will).

Also, note that in a filled shell, the total probability density will go as:

$$ \rho \propto x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2 $$

So, filled shells are spherical symmetric. (This is not obvious from looking at orbital graphics).

Similar reasoning can be applied to larger $l$ because for fixed $l$, the $Y_l^m$ form as $2l+1$ dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(3)$--that is, they are closed under rotations.

Answer (score 1):

The spherical harmonics are of the form $Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi)=f_{\ell,m}(\theta)e^{-i\varphi m}$ so $\vert Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2$ certainly not depend on $\varphi$.  Now by construction the spherical coordinate system identifies $\hat z$ as a special direction, from which it follows that $z=r\cos\theta$.  As a result, this makes results implicitly dependent on the orientation of $\hat z$.

Now, all is well except that in spherical potential you cannot really identify the direction of the $\hat z$ axis.  Since states with different $m$ all have the same energy, the total probability distribution is the sum of the probability distributions for the different $m$’s:
$$
P(r)=\frac{1}{2\ell+1}\sum_{m=-\ell}^\ell r^2 \vert R(r)Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2
\tag{1}\\
= \frac{r^2R^2(r)}{2\ell+1}\left(\sum_m \vert Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2\right)\, .
$$
Note that $\sum_m \vert Y_{\ell m}(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2=\frac{2\ell+1}{4\pi}$ and so $P(r)$ *is* actually independent of $\theta$.

Now you may rightly ask why Eq.(1) and not
$$
r^2\vert\sum_{m} R(r)Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2
$$
i.e. why not add the amplitude first and then take the modulus square, which would lead to cross terms in the spherical harmonics and ruin the spherical symmetry.

This is a little technical but if you don’t know if you have prepared your system in any one of the $m$ states, then you actually need to add the probabilities, not the square of the sum of probability amplitudes.  Basically, when you don’t know the direction of your $\hat z$ axis, the system is in a so-called [mixed state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states), meaning you must consider a statistical mixture of various $m$ states rather than a superposition of $m$ states.

Note that one *can* define a unique $\hat z$ axis using the direction of a magnetic or an electric field, but in such cases you ruin the spherical symmetry and the different $m$ states no longer have the energy.